# Imported model only visible in orthographic views?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, import, external-applications

The model was created in [Creo](https://www.ptc.com/en/products/cad/creo). When importing the model into blender I only can see it in *orthographic views* (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) but not in any *user perspective*. I already checked clipping and that's not the issue.

[image: my model with a front orthographic view[![the object disappears in user perspective]

[image]

**Q:** What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the imported mode, or upload your .blend for review? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=Y7vYMYNQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Y7vYMYNQ/)

Comment: Oh, er, for the future, you should add that to your question. The formatting breaks in the comments.

Comment: sorry, I'm still a newbie and try it for the first time

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in the n panel of the 3d view with your object selected in the Outliner, the dimensions of your object are 2.4km by 1.35km by 2.509km:

[image]

So that might be an issue, since the viewport clipping ends at 1km. In any way, it is hard to believe you want an object multiple kilometers in size, so just press <kbd>s</kbd> followed by something like 0.001 to scale it down in order to be able to see it. Or you could also check the clipping one more time and this time set it to something appropriate for the enormous size of the object like 10 and 10000.

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked

Comment: If that works, please accept the answer for future visitors. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour @LokeshShanmuga